# C++ матрично-векторное умножение ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ и warning C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пытаюсь понять последовательное и паралельное программирование по книге http://www.hpcc.unn.ru/multicore/materials/ippcm/book.pdf (стр 132) Но остановилась уже на последовательном алгоритме, так как в книге есть неточности.

Задача матрично-векторного умножения.

**Выдает ошибки**(скидываю весь код, т.к. не знаю из-за чего ошибка):

> 59): warning C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная
>   переменная "RowCount"
>
> 61): warning C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная
>   переменная "ColCount"
>
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl
>   PrintVector(double *,int)" (?PrintVector@@YAXPANH@Z) в функции _main
>
> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl
>   PrintMatrix(double *,int,int)" (?PrintMatrix@@YAXPANHH@Z) в функции
>   _main
>
> 2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 неразрешенных внешних элементов

**Подскажите пжл в чем ошибки?**

```
int main() {
    double *pMatrix=NULL,
           *pVector=NULL,
           *pResultVector=NULL;
    int Size, RowCount, ColCount;
    // Function for memory allocation and data initialization
    void ProcessInitialization(double* &pMatrix, double* &pVector, double* &pResultVector, int Size);
    {
        // Setting the size of initial matrix and vector
        do
        {
            printf("\nEnter size of the initial objects: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &Size);
            printf("\nChosen objects size = %d\n", Size);
            if (Size <= 0)
                printf("\nSize of objects must be greater than 0!\n");
        }
        while (Size <= 0);
        // Memory allocation
        pMatrix = new double [Size * Size];
        pVector = new double [Size];
        pVector = new double [Size];
        pResultVector = new double [Size];
    }
    // Function for simple initialization of matrix and vector elements
    void DummyDataInitialization(double* pMatrix, double* pVector, int Size);
    {
        int i, j; // Loop variables
        for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            pVector[i] = 1;
            for (j = 0; j < Size; j++)
                pMatrix[i * Size + j] = i;
        }
    }
    // Function for formatted matrix output
    void PrintMatrix(double* pMatrix, int RowCount, int ColCount);
    {
        int i, j; // Loop variables
        for (i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < ColCount; j++)
                printf("%7.4f ", pMatrix[i * ColCount + j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    // Function for formatted vector output
    void PrintVector(double* pVector, int Size);
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
            printf("%7.4f ", pVector[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    // Matrix and vector output
    printf("Initial Matrix: \n");
    PrintMatrix(pMatrix, Size, Size);
    printf("Initial Vector: \n");
    PrintVector(pVector, Size);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Не надо постить картинки, приведите сам код. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @freim Спасибо за совет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Перед использованием переменных их необходимо инициализировать значением:

   `int Size = 0, RowCount = 0, ColCount = 0;`

   > 59): warning C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "RowCount"
   >
   > 61): warning C4700: использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "ColCount"
2. При определении функции после ее сигнатуры не должно быть ";":

   `void DummyDataInitialization(double* pMatrix, double* pVector, int Size) {...}`

   > error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl PrintVector(double *,int)" (?PrintVector@@YAXPANH@Z) в функции _main
   >
   > error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl
   >   PrintMatrix(double *,int,int)" (?PrintMatrix@@YAXPANHH@Z) в функции _main
   >
   > 2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 неразрешенных внешних элементов
3. Функции необходимо определять в глобальной области видимости, а не внутри другой функции.

   `void PrintMatrix(double * pMatrix, int RowCount, int ColCount) {...}
   void PrintVector(double * pVector, int Size) {...}
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {...}`

Comment: Пункт 3 у вас как бы подразумевает, что такое можно, но не принято... :(

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.